# Why doesn't Erlang/OTP use several supervisors (or does it)?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

Looking at the documentation for OTP, it appears that a typical way to set up these systems is to have a single supervisor monitoring multiple workers:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html

That would work great until the machine running the supervisor crashes or gets cut off from the machines with the workers. So is there a reason not to have several supervisors, say one per machine?

Comment: I don't think you'd want to supervise processes on a different node (or machine). So, no, at least one supervisor per node sounds good.

Comment: This might help http://learnyousomeerlang.com/distributed-otp-applications

Comment: a better description is one supervision tree per node and per application, but several application per node, and several nodes when reliability is required... see [lyse](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/supervisors#from-bad-to-good)

Comment: Re-read this: http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/des_princ.html#id63532 Everything not a circle is a supervisor. Where in this tree you draw the lines that separate different elements by node is entirely up to you -- even if you want to replicate the entire thing on several nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how an OTP application might be set up on one machine:

[image]

There's two `-behavior(application)` pieces running. Each one has a top-level `-behavior(supervisor)` modules. It's not unusual to have supervisors under other supervisors forming a supervision tree.

Supervision trees are great for managing workers, but high-availability in the face of machine failure is a separate problem. You could put a supervisor on on machine supervising workers on other machines, but if the supervisor-machine went down, you've still lost your whole tree.

For that kind of HA behavior, you need some external system that monitors machines/BEAMs and restarts things that go down. Depending on your system, you might need to write your code to locate and re-cluster with its peers. Neither of these things come free from OTP like the supervision tree does.

Comment: Agree with you, I will add that for High availability, there are a lot of choices to make: security level, scalability, heterogeneity, performances, which side of the CAP do we use... Not sure that a generic solution can fit all possibilities.